# Beginner: TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'func_names'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, spacy, sklearn-pandas

df['Pattern'] = df['phrases'].apply(lambda texte:Preprocess, func_names=['tokenizeTexte_0'])

```
import TreeTagger OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classifier.py", line 41, in <module>
    df['Pattern'] = df['phrases'].apply(lambda texte:Preprocess, func_names=['tokenizeTexte_0']) # modify the parameter each time you want to change the preprocess steps
  File "/home/ke/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 3194, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1472, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "/home/k/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 3181, in <lambda>
    f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwds)
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'func_names'
```

The file looks like this  (it is an example since , i cannot put the original data)

```
id    phrases                       etiquette    sous-classe
23    C'est un psychiatre canadien.  Med          p
56    le Pr. Moldofsky, qui a fait   Med          n
émerger en 1975 cette maladie, 
45    en identifiant des plaintes    Fed          ne
78équivalentes par privation de sommeil 
chez des patientes volontaires. 
789    Reconnue Outre-Atlantique,    Ged          p
elle reste peu connue dans l'Hexagone.
```

Comment: I am trying to understand exactly what you want to do. You can three functions which need to be chained (one needs to happen before the other etc).

Do you want to be able to turn all 3 functions into one? Or do you wish to choose how many preprocessing steps to use?

Comment: @ValentinCalomme I would like to turn all 3 into function and also be able to choose which preprocessing steps I use. so for example , in my global function I can choose if i use only lemmatisation or just lemmatisation and removing of stopwords. So instead to have three function , i would have one which i according to condition i could use diffrent steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic way to do this is to store the functions in a dictionary where you use keys to find the function you want. Here is an example below where I create a function `combine_functions` which takes a list of strings as an argument. This allows you to pick which function should be run in which order. Technically, this also allows you to run the same function multiple times.

```py
def func1(x):

    print("I am func1")

    return x


def func2(x):

    print("I am func2")

    return x


def func3(x):

    print("I am func3")

    return x


def combine_functions(x, func_names=[]):

    functions = {"func1": func1,
                 "func2": func2,
                 "func3": func3}

    for func_name in func_names:

        x = functions[func_name](x)

    return x
```

Comment: Thank you , I will try and comming back to you.

Comment: i HAVE THIS ERROR line 62, in Preprocess
    for func_name in func_names:
TypeError: ("'function' object is not iterable", 'occurred at index 0')  , could you check my answer I edit my first question to include the result with yours

Comment: the func_names argument should be a list of strings, you passed tokenizeTexte_0 but should have passed ["tokenizeTexte_0"]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be you are not understanding the `apply` function correctly.
In `apply`, you just pass the function name without the parantheses, pandas will appropriately send the arguments to the function based on lambda.

So its wrong to do

```
df['Pattern'] = df.apply(lambda row:Preprocess(row['phrases'], tokenizeTexte_0),...)
```

You just need to do:

```
df['Pattern'] = df.apply(lambda x:Preprocess ,...)
```

Now, you want to work only on the `"phrases"`. So no need to use `.apply` on the whole dataframe. You can just use:

```
df['Pattern'] = df['phrases'].apply(lambda texte:Preprocess, ...)
```

Secondly, your `Preprocess` function requires the second argument `"func_names"` as a list. Which you can pass in the apply (not in the Preprocess), like this:

"**Corrected**"

```
df['Pattern'] = df['phrases'].apply(Preprocess, 
                                    func_names=['tokenizeTexte_0'])
```

Comment: I corected the script using your proposition but I have an error :df['Pattern'] = df['phrases'].apply(lambda texte:Preprocess, func_names=['tokenizeTexte_0']); i got this errror : f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwds)
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'func_names'

Comment: @EMMAKENJI Yes, that was my error. Since you have already defined the function, no need to use lambda, just put name there. See my edit.